# Pontos e acentos em URLs com mod_rewrite

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewrite

Notei que muitos sistemas que usam `mod_rewrite` (ou equivalente) costumam não suportar URLs com acentos, geralmente eles substituem os caracteres como ponto (dot) por hífen (`-`) e os acentos por suas respectivas letras sem acento.

Minha duvida é a seguinte, usar pontos e/ou acentos em urls podem ocasionar algum tipo de problema ou tem algum motivo para não usá-los?

Isto é uma questão de SEO ou de uso da navegação por parte do usuário são caracteres que podem atrapalhar em algo, como navegação ou estruturas?

Minha "regra" que pretendo usar para urls reescritas ([regex](/questions/tagged/regex)):

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\/.]+)$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ao pesqusiar pelo termo *rfc dot path*, finalmente encontrei o motivo desta "polemica"

### O problema com o ponto nas URLs - `.` (dot)

Não `há problemas` em usar pontos em urls (mesmo que reescritas) como por exemplo:

```
http://example/project/ola.mundo.novo
```

ou supondo que vamos criar uma url `falsa`, como:

```
http://example/project/index.php/ola-mundo.html
```

O problema é quando ocorre de usar assim:

```
http://example/project/test./
```

Para o servidor `/project/test./` e `/project/test/` são a mesma coisa, mas está visível que não são.

> Note que o problema NÃO ocorre se fizer isto `/project/.test/`, já que existem arquivos que começam com ponto apenas.

O motivo dos URLs reescritos não usarem pontos é para evitar esta situação ou seja facilitar a canonicalização das URLs (normalização de URL).

Um exemplo mais claro do problema, crie um arquivo na sua pasta física do localhost:

```
/var/www/images/test.jpg
```

Acesse `http://localhost/images/test.jpg` e depois tente acessar todos estes:

- `http://localhost/images/test.jpg.`
- `http://localhost/images/test.jpg...`
- `http://localhost/images/test.jpg....`
- `http://localhost/images/test.jpg.....`
- `http://localhost/images/test.jpg......`
- `http://localhost/images/test.jpg.......`

Todas URLs serão entregues ao cliente (navegador por exemplo) como imagem `test.jpg`.

### Normalização de URL (ou canonicalização de URL)

<sup>Termo em inglês para pesquisas seria `URL normalization` ou `URL canonicalization`</sup>

Normalização de URL (ou canonicalização de URL) é o processo pelo qual as URLs são modificadas e padronizadas de uma forma consistente. O objectivo do processo de normalização é transformar um URL em um `URL normalizado` ou canônica por isso, é possível determinar se duas URLs diferentes sintaticamente pode ser equivalente.

Os motores de busca utilizam normalização de URL, a fim de atribuir importância a páginas da web e reduzir a indexação de páginas duplicadas. Crawlers executam normalização de URL, a fim de evitar o rastreamento o mesmo recurso mais de uma vez.

Tipos de normalização (as seguintes normalizações são descritas pelo [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)):

- A remoção do índice do diretório. Índices diretório padrão geralmente não são necessários em URLs:

  `http://www.example.com/a/index.html` → `http://www.example.com/a/`
- Substituindo IP com nome de domínio. Verifique se o endereço IP mapeia para um nome de domínio canônico:

  `http://208.77.188.166/` → `http://www.example.com/` (algo que ajuda nisto é o header `Host: domain`)
- Removendo duplicado corta caminhos que incluem duas barras adjacentes pode ser convertido para um:

  `http://www.example.com/foo//bar.html` → `http://www.example.com/foo/bar.html`
- Removendo ou adicionando `www` como o primeiro rótulo de domínio. Geralmente ambas urls apontam para as mesmas páginas:

  `http://www.example.com/` → `http://example.com/`
- Remoção do `?` quando a consulta é vazia. Quando a consulta é vazia, pode não haver necessidade para a `?`:

  `http://www.example.com/display?` → `http://www.example.com/display`
- Adiciona `/` ao diretórios:

  `http://www.example.com/alice` → `http://www.example.com/alice/` (geralmente os servidores como Apache e Ngnix já fazem o redirecionamento se for uma pasta real).

  No entanto, não há nenhuma maneira de saber se um componente URL caminho representa um diretório ou não. [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) menciona que se o URL redireciona para o URL último do exemplo, então isso é uma indicação de que eles são equivalentes.
- Removendo seguimentos de pontos (dot-segmentos). Os segmentos `..` e `.` Pode ser removido a partir de um URL de acordo com o algoritmo descrito na [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt):

  `http://www.example.com/../a/b/../c/./d.html` → `http://www.example.com/a/c/d.html`

  No entanto, se se um componente `..` foi removido, ex: `b/..`, é um link simbólico para um diretório com um pai diferente, isto `b/..` irá resultar em um caminho e um URL diferente. Em casos raros, dependendo do servidor web, isso pode até ser verdade para o diretório raiz (e.g. `//www.example.com/..` may not be equivalente to `//www.example.com/`. (este é o provavel motivos de evitar `.`)

Então você me pergunta: *Guilherme eu devo então evitar os pontos nas minhas URLs reescritas?*
Eu digo que é uma solução, mas não é a unica, se você está usando `mod_rewrite`, provavelmente estará usando uma linguagem como PHP por exemplo e através desta linguagem você pode detectar se a URL tem pontos no final, como por exemplo:

```bsh
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\/.]+)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Este RewriteRule gera a variavel `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` e você pode comparar está variavel com a variavel `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, ambos serão diferentes. Ou então você pode apenas usar `REQUEST_URI` combinado com `rtrim` para verificar e fazer um redirecionamento permanente, como por exemplo:

```php
<?php
$req = rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');//Remove barra do final

if ($req !== rtrim($req, '.')) {
    //Usei X-PHP-Response-Code para compatibilidade com alguns servidores Fast-CGI ou semelhantes
    header('X-PHP-Response-Code: 301', true, 301);
}
```

Eu acredito que você possa fazer isto por `.htaccess` também, assim que tiver condições de produzir algo eficiente irei editar a resposta.

### O problema dos acentos nas URLs

Os acentos tem como motivo principal de serem evitados por causa canonicalização, mas não é o `mesmo` problema do ponto `.` (dot), o problema é devido ao caracteres `equivalentes` porém `diferentes`, por exemplo:

- Em um documento PHP salvo em ANSI o `á` será codificado como `%E1`:

  ```php
    <?php
    echo 'http://example/', urlencode('á-é-í');//Output: http://example/%E1-%E9-%ED
  ```
- Em um documento PHP salvo em UTF-8 o `á` será codificado como `%C3%A1`:

  ```php
    <?php
    echo 'http://example/', urlencode('á-é-í');//Output: http://example/%C3%A1-%C3%A9-%C3%AD
  ```

Isto é apenas um exemplo, outro seria `ß` e `ss`

Existe soluções para evitar este problema e não usar acentos é uma delas, porém há outras maneiras, assim que possível irei fornecer um exemplo.

### Unicode canonicalização

> **Nota:** apesar de alguns pontos serem os mesmos do já descritos aqui, o está parte se trata do [RFC 2279](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2279.txt)

Em Unicode, muitas letras acentuadas pode ser representada em mais de caminho. Por exemplo, e pode ser representado em Unicode como o caractere Unicode `U+0065` (LATIN PEQUENAS CARTA E) seguido do caractere `U+0301` (que combina acento agudo), mas também pode ser representado como o personagem pré-comprimida `U+00E9` (LATIN PEQUENA E COM CARTA aguda). Isso faz comparação de seqüência mais complicada, uma vez que cada representação possível de uma sequência de caracteres contendo tais glifos devem ser consideradas. Para lidar com isso, Unicode fornece o mecanismo de equivalência canônica. Neste contexto, a canonicalização é a normalização Unicode.

Codificações de comprimento variável no padrão Unicode, em particular, `UTF-8`, pode causar uma necessidade adicional de canonicalização em algumas situações. Ou seja, pela norma, em `UTF-8` só há uma sequencia de byte válido para qualquer caractere Unicode, mas algumas sequencias de bytes são inválidos, ou seja, não pode ser obtido através da codificação de qualquer sequencia de caracteres Unicode em `UTF-8`. Algumas implementações de decodificador desleixado pode aceitar sequências de bytes inválidos como entrada e produzir um caractere Unicode válida como saída para tal sequencia. Se alguém usa um decodificador, alguns caracteres Unicode tem efetivamente mais do que uma sequência de byte correspondente: um válido e alguns inválidos. Isto pode levar a problemas de segurança semelhantes ao descrito na secção anterior. Portanto, se alguém quiser aplicar alguns filtros (por exemplo, uma expressão regular escrito em `UTF-8`) para `UTF-8` cordas que serão posteriormente passados ​​para um decodificador que permite sequências de bytes inválidos, deve canonizar as cordas antes de passa-los para o filtro. Neste contexto, a canonicalização é o processo de traduzir cada caractere sequencia de caracteres para a sua sequência de byte único válido. Uma alternativa para a canonicalização é rejeitar quaisquer sequências contendo sequencias de bytes inválidos.

Fontes:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonicalization
- [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)
- [RFC 2279](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2279.txt)

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo já deu pra entender que você não sabe entender uma critica construtiva e não aceita bem criticas, várias vezes tentei lhe ajudar quando você recebeu downvotes de outros usuários, para reverter a situação e você interpretou minha ajuda como critica negativa apenas, sinceramente fique tranquilo não irei mais lhe importunar, vou deixar vc pensar o que quiser do downvotes que vc receber da comunidade, eu não me meto mais nas suas respostas e nem ajudarei mais, porque se com todo esse tempo você não entendeu como funciona significa que não vai entender nunca. Adeus.

Answer (score 2):

Pontos e caracteres especiais podem interferir na hora de receber os dados na sua programação, o ideal é que se use um método `urlencode` ou `urldecode`, isso existe para várias linguagens web ou similar, para poder manipular essas variáveis sem dar erro ou perder campos.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, como eles poderiam interferir (tanto o ponto quanto os acentos)? Poderia me dar um exemplo? Grato. **Nota:** Acredito que não seja necessário `urldecode` pois ao entregar a resposta via GET para o servidor elas já estão decodificadas.

Comment: O urldecode se fará necessário quando utilizar o urlencode antes.

Comment: Já a necessidade do urlEncode, será para que ao criar um link dinamicamente não corra o risco de passar espaços, pontos e barra principalmente, estas com certeza quebrarão seu link. Já acentos e outros caracteres especiais poderão sofrer variações de acordo com o charset que utilizar, intervenção entre diferentes linguagens e outras caracteristicas.

Comment: Michel eu entendo o uso de urlencode, urldecode, etc. Mas os links gerados não devem conter acentos nem espaços, então urlencode não vai servir, na verdade eu criei uma função usando ela ficou assim `$text = iconv($encode, 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $text); return trim($text, '-');` e transforma uma string assim `-á é í ó . oi Olá Mundo-` em `a-e-i-o-.-oi-Ola-mundo`. Sobre charset e codificação já consegui resolver, eu só preciso definir se usar acentos e pontos pode ocasionar algum outro problemas que não seja de um link, mas na questão da requisição, pois notei que...

Comment: ...muitos sites evitam o uso de pontos e acentos, você poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Hj em dia é possivel até registrar domínios com acento. o Registro.br aceita registro diferente para www.requisição.com.br e www.requisicao.com.br, hj o navegador interpreta tranquilamente, a questão é mais como vc recebe a requisição. Muitos sites utilizam frameworks ou ferramentas, como wordpress, joomla, blogger, entre componentes de desenvolvimento em todas linguagens, já oferecem soluções prontas, que por convenção manipulam o url sem acentos.

Comment: Michel obrigado pelo esforço, quando me referi aos sites, eu me referia as páginas deles e não dominios. Após pesquisar no RFC eu encontrei o motivo disto e formulei uma resposta espero que leia, obrigado.