# Unlink: No such file or directory

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Olá, estava desenvolvendo as páginas e de repente ocorreu o seguinte `Warning`:

```
Warning: unlink(upload/publicacoes/Empresa Demonstração LTDA/Utilitários/Informações/2017/149029774958d4239521de6883c7046854e04138c55680ffde90a61.pdf): No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\MettaCont\html\deletePublicationA.php on line 30
```

No sistema que desenvolvo é criado um sistema de pastas onde é armazenado as informações, mas repentinamente esse erro aparece quando eu vou deletar a publicação, em algumas vezes não todas, e eu não encontro o erro, sendo que o arquivo dele está lá, como na imagem:
[image: Print]
Meu Código que deleta publicacões:

```
<?php
require "conexao.php";
$pdo = conectar();

$codigo=$_GET['cod_publicacao'];
try{

$buscaSQL = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_publicacao WHERE cod_publicacao = ?");
$buscaSQL->bindValue(1, $codigo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$buscaSQL->execute();
$row = $buscaSQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$publicacao = $row['publicacao'];
$ano = $row['ano'];
$tipo_publicacao = $row['fk_tipo'];
$fk_empresa = $row['fk_empresa'];
$arq=$row['arquivo'];

$searchSQL = $pdo->prepare("SELECT tbl_tipo_publicacao.cod_tipo_public, tbl_tipo_publicacao.tipo_publicacao, tbl_empresa.cod_empresa, tbl_empresa.razao_social FROM tbl_tipo_publicacao, tbl_empresa WHERE cod_tipo_public = ? AND cod_empresa = ?");

$searchSQL->bindValue(1, $tipo_publicacao, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$searchSQL->bindValue(2, $fk_empresa, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$searchSQL->execute();
$line = $searchSQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$tipo_public = $line['tipo_publicacao'];
$razao_social = $line['razao_social'];
echo $arq;
$pasta = "upload/publicacoes/{$razao_social}/{$tipo_public}/{$publicacao}/{$ano}/";
unlink ($pasta.$arq);

$deleteSQL=$pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM tbl_publicacao WHERE cod_publicacao=:codigo");
$deleteSQL->bindValue(':codigo', $codigo);
//$deleteSQL->execute();

if($deleteSQL):
echo"<script>alert('Deletado com Sucesso!')</script>";
//echo "<script>window.history.back()</script>";
else:
echo"<script>alert('Falha ao deletar publicação!')</script>";
echo "<script>window.history.back()</script>";
endif;

}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "ERROR: " .$e->getMessage()."<br>";
    echo "ERROR: " .$e->getCode();

}
?>
```

Estou usando padrão `utf8mb4` no banco, caso isso seja importante

Comment: Posso estar totalmente enganado, mas alguns sistemas operacionais somados com o problemático PHP podem dar problemas ao utilizar caminhos/arquivos usando caracteres acentuados (não-ASCII).

Comment: Leia esse post http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60316/pontos-e-acentos-em-urls-com-mod-rewrite

Comment: @Saul, não tenho certeza, mas acredito que você terá que dar escape no nome do diretório, devido ao uso de espaços

Comment: Consegui resolver utilizando o utf8_decode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você pode observar [nesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989096/unlink-not-working-with-space-in-foldername-path) pergunta no SOen, o problema é que o sistema operacional espera que os espaços sejam escapados.

Outro problema que eu vejo é o uso de caracteres não-ANSII, como `ç`.

Para sanar o problema, primeiramente você deve escapar os espaços. Este código deve resolver este problema:

```
$filepath = str_replace(" ", "\\ ", $filepath);
```

O segundo problema é mais complicado, pois depende muito do sistema operacional e do charset que você está passando.
Para evitar tratar todos os casos possíveis, recomendo que você use uma string sem caracteres especiais.

Um jeito rápido e fácil de fazer isso é convertendo a string atual:

```
$filepath = iconv('UTF-8', 'ANSI//IGNORE', $filepath);
```

Observação: Estou considerando que a sua string esteja em UTF-8. Ajuste caso seja necessário.