# Caminho para acesso de pastas html ,css,php etc

Tags: php, html, css

Alguém poderia me explicar esse sistema de nives para acessar pasta no uso de linguagens como html,css e php (../)(.../)(./).?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### O ".." (dois pontos) e o "." (ponto)

Conforme [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt):

1. Se o caminho começar com `../` ou `./` então eles serão removidos do prefixo:

   `../a/b/c` → `a/b/c`
2. Se o caminho começar com `/./`, `/../` eles serão trocado por `/`

   `/./a/b/c` → `/a/b/c`
3. Se terminar com `/.`, `/./`, `/..` irá remover o próprio `/.` e `/..`:

   `/a/b/c/..` → `/a/b/c/` e `/a/b/c/.` → `/a/b/c/`
4. Se terminar com `/./` e `/../` irá remover um item:

   `/a/b/c/../` → `/a/b/`
5. Se `/../` estiver no meio irá remover o prefixo (semelhante a explicação 4):

   `/a/b/../c/` → `/a/c/`
6. Se `./` estiver no meio terá o mesmo comportamento que a explicação 2:

   `/a/b/./c/` → `/a/b/c/`

> Alguns detalhes extras em [*Pontos e acentos em URLs com mod_rewrite*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/61127/3635)

Claro que a leitura do *RFC 3986* é algo um pouco difícil, até mesmo para quem já tem alguma experiencia, alguns dos exemplos efetuei com testes, para resumir o `..` seria para subir um nível de pasta (se não estiver no prefixo) e o `./` seria para apontar o próprio local.

Imagine que tenhamos uma pasta com esta estrutura:

```
./teste.html
./pasta
├── index.html
└── ./paginas
    ├── a.html
    └── b.html
```

Se no `/pasta/paginas/a.html` clicar no link:

```
<a href="../index.html">teste</a>
```

Ele irá direcionar para `/pasta/index.html`

Mas se o link for:

```
<a href="./index.html">teste</a>
```

Então ele irá tentar procurar `/pasta/paginas/index.html`, o que no exemplo não existe.

E se em `/pasta/paginas/b.html` tiver:

```
<a href="../a.html">teste</a>
```

Vai procurar algo como `/pasta/a.html`, o que seria errado no exemplo, deveria ser:

```
<a href="./a.html">teste</a>
```

Para ficar no mesmo nível de `/pasta/paginas/a.html`

Se tiver um link como `/teste.html` ou `/../teste.html` ou `/./teste.html` ele vai procurar algo na raiz definida, no caso do exemplo vai procurar algo como `/a.html` para todos os links citados, porque o `/` no prefixo move para a raiz.

Claro que isto tudo depende de lugar como foi descrito, o mesmo vale para CSS e até para quando se usa `include` no PHP.

---

### O "..." (três pontos)

Este **não** esta descrito no RFC, provavelmente a maior parte das aplicações como servidores HTTP e navegadores interpretará isto como um arquivo ou como um caminho inacessivel, no Apache por exemplo ele emite uma resposta **HTTP 403 Forbidden** e geralmente retorna algo como:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /.../ on this server.
```

Ou como *não encontrado*

Comment: `RFC` eficiente.

Comment: @Edilson na verdade ele é somente as "normas" que devem ser seguidas, cada navegador ou servidor pode implementar como quiser, mas se não seguir é claro que faria uma série de sistemas falharem.

Answer (score 5):

É comum as páginas de uma Web usarem URLs relativos contendo apenas um caminho parcial e um nome do arquivo.

Em caminhos relativos ao documento, usamos ponto-ponto-barra **../** para indicar que se deve voltar um nível.

Exemplos:

1: Para andar do diretório **dirc** ao diretório **dira**:

```
../dira/nomeArquivo.ext
```

2: Para andar do diretório **dire** para o diretório **dira**

```
../../dira/nomeArquivo.ext
```

3: Para andar do diretório **dire** para o diretório **dirb**

```
../../dirb/nomeArquivo.ext
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**./** mesma pasta.

Comment: Obrigado !!!!!!

Comment: Léo, só pra avisar não fui eu quem negativou e não sei o motivo disto, mas se quiser uma dica seria legal trocar esta imagem por texto de verdade. Menos as pastas, não pense que todo downvote é arbitrário, a maioria talvez seja uma maneira de dizer "você pode melhorar". De uma lida no META quando puder: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=downvote

Comment: Sim, mas a imagem das pastas esta boa, basta pegar a parte que é texto na imagem e converter em texto de verdade. O que lhe parece legal nem sempre é útil para outras pessoas da maneira que você faz, por exemplo tem um colega aqui no site que as imagens do domínio `.imgur.com` não carregam, assim como outros dominios de host de imagens, isto porque na empresa dele tem um proxy que bloqueia, outro problema é que existem pessoas deficientes visuais que por incrível que pareça, trabalham em nossa área (TI), usam leitores de tela, mesmo que raro. Como eu disse a imagem das pastas é aproveitável.

Comment: Upvote não tem nada haver com a situação, deves fazer isto visando ajudar e não ganhar algo, tem que entender como eu já lhe expliquei outras vezes, que algo para você pode parecer: bom, útil, funcional ou a melhor ferramenta do mundo. Mas para outros usuários que acessam suas respostas pode ser algo impraticável ou inacessível. A sugestões que sempre lhe dou são para você melhorar e suas respostas serem mais úteis para a "comunidade toda", não tem nada haver com "chantagem de votos" ou "troca de votos".

Answer (score 3):

`../` pode ser lido como uma pasta acima.

Considere esta estrutura:

```
dominio.com/html
dominio.com/images
```

Imagine que uma página da pasta `/html` precisa acessar uma imagem da pasta `/image`.

se você souber o domínio, vai fazer algo como

```
<img scr="http://www.dominio.com/image/image01.png">
```

E vai ser feliz até precisar usar este código em outro domínio.

Já se fizer:

```
<img scr="../image/image01.png">
```

A página vai entender onde esta a imagem. E se quiser reaproveitar o código, ou mudar o domínio no futuro, poderá fazê-lo sem dificuldade. E será feliz para sempre.

Note que pode aninhar pastas repetindo o padrão. Assim `../../` significa, duas pastas acima, e assim por diante.

`./` refere-se a mesma pasta. Na prática, é redundante e desnecessário.

`.../` não sei. Nunca vi.