# Como linkar arquivos em pastas diferentes?

Tags: html, html5, link, diretório, linkagem

Estou com dificuldade para fazer um link entre duas páginas HTML, a hierarquia das pasta é esta:

[image: hierarquia de pastas]

Eu quero linkar o arquivo:

J:\Totem_App\XPLACES\acess\cid_vitoria\1_acru.html

que tem um botão no seu código para o arquivo "***00_menu_vitoria_xingu.html***" contido no que seria o diretório raiz do site.

```
<a href="/../../00_menu_vitoria_xingu.html" target="_parent" 
class="bcontraste">LINK</a>
```

Acontece que desta forma estou tendo um "*página não encontrada*" estou voltando dois diretórios certo? Usando:

```
/../../
```

? Pois volta 2 diretórios o 'cid_vitoria'e depois o 'acess', então qual é a forma funcional de linkar os arquivos?

Comment: Tenta assim href="./../../00_menu_vitoria_xingu.html" ou href="~/00_menu_vitoria_xingu.html" as vezes resolve...

Comment: ok vou testar! Obrigado.

Comment: @hugocsl funcionou. Obrigado! Mas você pode me explicar a lógica do porquê /../../ não ter funcionado? ./ significa que ele deve parar na pasta raiz é isso?

Comment: dib publiquei mais explicações na resposta para sua pergunta abaixo. Se te ajudou considere marca-la como aceita :) `✔`

Comment: Você está "subindo níveis" de hierarquia de pastas com /../ quando deveria subir com ../ Se você iniciar com / ele não contará os ..
Tenho um artigo que pode lhe ajudar a entender melhor, com exemplos e imagens
[Artigo Linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6857777587935072256/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta assim `href="./../../00_menu_vitoria_xingu.html"` que deve funcionar. *O arquivo está na terceira pasta para cima*, por isso o `./` extra no caminho que  apontar o próprio local.

---

Aqui tem uma explicação. sobre o caminho dos arquivos.

Veja esse pequeno trecho de uma resposta em outra pergunta

1. Se o caminho começar com `../` ou `./` então eles serão removidos do prefixo:

   `../a/b/c` → `a/b/c`
2. Se o caminho começar com `/./`, `/../` eles serão trocado por `/`

   `/./a/b/c` → `/a/b/c`
3. Se terminar com `/.`, `/./`, `/..` irá remover o próprio `/.` e `/..`:

   `/a/b/c/..` → `/a/b/c/` e `/a/b/c/.` → `/a/b/c/`
4. Se terminar com `/./` e `/../` irá remover um item:

   `/a/b/c/../` → `/a/b/`
5. Se `/../` estiver no meio irá remover o prefixo (semelhante a explicação 4):

   `/a/b/../c/` → `/a/c/`
6. Se `./` estiver no meio terá o mesmo comportamento que a explicação 2:

   `/a/b/./c/` → `/a/b/c/`

> Alguns detalhes extras em [Caminho para acesso de pastas html ,css,php etc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198422/caminho-para-acesso-de-pastas-html-css-php-etc)

Claro que a leitura do *RFC 3986* é algo um pouco difícil, até mesmo para quem já tem alguma experiencia, alguns dos exemplos efetuei com testes, para resumir o `..` seria para subir um nível de pasta (se não estiver no prefixo) e o `./` seria para apontar o próprio local.

Crédito ao: Guilherme Nascimento https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento

OBS: A opção com o <kbd>~</kbd> Busca o arquivo direto da pasta raiz, no seu caso a J, tentei achar uma referência de pq não funcionou, mas infelizmente não achei. Então desconsidere essa opção rss