# Como chamar uma página modal em um navbar no bootstrap?

Tags: php, javascript, twitter-bootstrap, link, nav-bar

Estou desenvolvendo um site o qual eu preciso chamar um modal no submenu de um navbar do bootstrap, porém, o arquivo em php com a página que eu gostaria de chamar está em uma pasta diferente do arquivo que foi criado o navbar. Procurei em um monte de sites e não achei uma maneira que desse certo, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Código do meu navbar:

```
public function get_menu() {            
                echo <<<HTML
                <nav class="navbar my-nav navbar-expand-lg">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sistema</a>
                  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                  </button>                 
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Início <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>                       
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Cadastrar</a>                          
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">                            
                              <a class="dropdown-item menu_item" href="#">Perfil</a>
                              <a class="dropdown-item menu_item" href="#">Usuário</a>
                        </li>                       
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Consultar</a>                           
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">                              
                              <a class="dropdown-item menu_item" href="#">Perfil</a>
                              <a class="dropdown-item menu_item" href="#">Usuário</a>                  
                            </li>                                               
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sair</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul> 
                </div>
            </nav>     
HTML;


        }
```

Estrutura de pastas:

C:\Projeto\view\principal\funcoes_principal.php (arquivo que contém o navbar, tela principal)
C:\Projeto\view\modal\index.php (arquivo com o modal)

Comment: Aline poste o código que já desenvolveu para receber mais ajuda, leia também https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Cole o código da sua navbar e a estrutura de arquivo para melhor compreensão para que a comunidade possa ajudar.

Comment: Você não conseguiu chamar o arquivo php que está num diretório diferente do aquivo que contém o navbar? Se é isso, coloque o código do arquivo principal e como está sendo realizado a chamada. Isso já seria um 'start' para o pessoal pode ajudar. Nota: Evite divulgar informações confidenciais, que por ventura podem estar no código.

Comment: Isso vai te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198422/caminho-para-acesso-de-pastas-html-css-php-etc

Comment: Aline aqui tem a documentação do Modal do Bootstrap. Se ninguém aqui te responde lá com certeza tem a resposta! https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals primeiro vc tem que abrir o modal clicando no Menu, depois fazer um includ para chamar a outra página dentro do modal.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi seria uma navbar com um modal e o carregamento de páginas dentro do modal e o modal ser exibido com o conteúdo requisitado, fiz uma função onde você pode abrir várias páginas a partir de uma função, assim poderá reaproveitar o código para carregar quantas páginas você quiser.

Considerando que sua página já carregou os arquivos do Bootstrap e Jquery, segue um exemplo.

No submenu do dropdown no evento do clique do mouse, chamei a função javascript abrirPaginaNoModal(); e nela você passa como parâmetro a url (diretório/arquivo) que será requisitado e aberto dentro do modal, logo carregado, a função chama o modal com o evento .modal('show'); para carregar o modal visualmente. Espero que funcione.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pagina</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Menu dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="abrirPaginaNoModal('diretorio/arquivo.html')">Abrir pagina 01</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="abrirPaginaNoModal('diretorio/arquivo-2.html')">Abrir pagina 02</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modalPaginas">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">MODAL</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function abrirPaginaNoModal(url){
  $(".modal-body").load(url); // chama diretório/arquivo dentro do corpo do modal
  $("#modalPaginas").modal('show'); // Abre o modal visualmente
}
</script>
```

Comment: Eu acho que não foi isso... vou tentar explicar melhor. Eu tenho uma pasta nomeada projeto e dentro dessa pasta tenho outra chamada view e dentro dessa pasta view uma pasta chamada principal com um arquivo php que contém uma função que gera uma navbar, esse arquivo é a minha tela principal do site.  Dentro da pasta view eu tenho uma outra pasta chamada modal, a qual eu fiz um modal que eu queria chamar no meu menu da página principal, só que eu não sei como chamar esse modal em um submenu por estar em um diretório/pasta diferente...

Comment: Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Seria mais fácil ajudá-la se postar aqui o seu código, e a estrutura de seu diretório,  e o quanto mais comentado o seu código para compreensão com que podem ajudá-la, ficará mais fácil com uma resposta adequada como deseja.

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar a chamada da seguinte forma:

```
"../modal/index.php" ou "../../(etc.)"
```

A cada "../", o sistema sobe um nível no caminho do path.

Comment: Não funcionou...

Comment: @Aline Aparece alguma mensagem de erro no console?

Comment: não, quando eu clico no submenu ele não acontece nada

Answer (score -2):

Dá um

```
<?php require "C:\Projeto\view\modal\index.php"; ?>
```

No arquivo C:\Projeto\view\principal\funcoes_principal.php do navbar

E coloca:

```
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
```

na linha da tag  do menu que vc quer chamar o modal.