# imagem não aparece no html 5

Tags: html5

Estou tentando colocar uma imagem em um painel utilizando HTML5 porém ela não está reconhecendo.

No painel padrão estava dessa forma:

```
<a href="index.html" class="site_title"><i class="fa fa-paw"></i> <span>MobiAbert</span> </a>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quero colocar a imagem da empresa ao invés do nome com um icone do lado. Fiz a seguinte alteração na linha:

```
<a href="index.html" class="site_title"> <img src="imagens/logomobi.png"/> </a>
```

Mas a imagem não aparece e fica dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Provavelmente o caminho da imagem está errado e está retornando uma resposta 404. Já verificou as ferramentas de desenvolvedor no seu navegador?

Comment: vc já conferiu se a extensão da imagem é mesmo .png ou se é gif ou jpg? Isso deve te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198422/caminho-para-acesso-de-pastas-html-css-php-etc

Comment: Talvez vc mudar para .jpeg funcione... tive esse mesmo problema e fiz essa alteração e deu certo...abraços

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz assim

```
<img src="imagens/foto.png" alt="Imagem de página não encontrada" width="330" height="202" />
```

O exemplo acima carrega a imagem chamada "foto.png" que está dentro da pasta "imagens".

**Atenção:** A pasta "imagens" deve estar na mesma pasta do seu arquivo .html.

**E agora uma ajudinha**

Tag 
Os principais atributos da tag  são:

**src:** indica o caminho da imagem dentro das pastas do web site.

**alt:** define um texto alternativo que será lido pelos navegadores de voz, também define um texto que será exibido caso a imagem não carregue.

**height:** define a altura da imagem. É importante definir esse atributo para que o navegador "reserve" o espaço no layout até que a imagem seja carregada.

**width:** define a largura da imagem. É importante definir esse atributo para que o navegador "reserve" o espaço no layout até que a imagem seja carregada.

**border:** apesar de não suportado no HTML5, pode ser necessário para retirar a borda de imagens que sejam links (border="0").