# Background image em branco

Tags: html, css

Estou tendo um problema com html, pois preciso adicionar uma imagem no fundo de um container e estou utilizando bootstrap, já tentei adicionar a class em um css separado, mas mesmo assim não funciona

```css
.bg-back{
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url("./imagem/bg.jpg");

}
```

```html
<main>
<section class="bg-back">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
<div class="container" align="center">
       <div class="input-group col-lg-6">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
           <span class="input-group-btn">
               <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Pesquisar</button>
           </span>
       </div>
   </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
</section>
</main>
```

Comment: Rick tire as aspas no `background-image` assim: `url(./imagem/bg.jpg)` se mesmo assim não funcionar é pq o caminho para sua pasta está errado, ai vc pode tentar colocar um " . " a mais no inicio do path, caso a imagem está uma pasta "fora" da pasta onde está seu arquivo `.css`. assim: " ../ " `background-image: url(../imagem/bg.jpg);`

Comment: @hugocsl deu certo, responde o tópico pra colocar a sua resposta com certa. Obrigado.

Comment: Valeu Rick já vou fazer, obrigado pela força!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rick acredito que o problema como falei no comentário é que está faltando um " . " no caminho do seu diretório para a pasta da imagem. Trocado de `./` para `../` Nessa resposta vc pode ler mais sobre o assunto se te interessar [Caminho para acesso de pastas html ,css,php etc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198422/caminho-para-acesso-de-pastas-html-css-php-etc)

Se a imagem está uma pasta "fora" da pasta onde está seu arquivo .css. vc deve fazer assim: " ../ " antes do nome da pasta:

```
background-image: url(../imagem/bg.jpg);
```

*Outra observação é que vc não precisa colocar aspas envolta do caminho dentro do `url()` apesar de alguns considerarem isso uma boa prática.*