# Nao consigo colocar a imagem ao lado do titulo usando tag link

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

```html
<title>Biografia - João da Silva</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.png">
<h1>Sobre mim</h1>

<p>Moro em São Paulo mas atendo clientes do mundo todo. Sou conhecido por fazer produtos de qualidade, durabilidade e que agregam valor para meus clientes.</p>
```

(Mesmo usando o diretorio da imagem depois de href eu nao consigo colocar a imagem)
(que seria este)
(C:\Users\Dante\Desktop\Programação\pasta-alura\html-css-javascript\favicon.png)

Comment: você quer mostrar a imagem na aba do navegador ou na sua página?

Comment: quero mostrar na aba

Comment: tenta dar um `Ctrl + F5` na sua página para ver se aparece

Comment: Sua imagem tem que estar na mesma pasta que seu .html, ai basta coloca a tag `<link rel="icon" href="favicon.png">` dentro do `head`. E confere se a extenção da imagem é mesmo .PNG ou outra coisa

Comment: Qual browser tá usando?

Comment: to usando o Chrome e o Firefox Leandro.

Comment: Hugo eu ainda nao coloquei o head, sera que e por isso pois a imagem ja esta na mesma pasta

Comment: Gabriel leia a resposta abaixo, ela vai te ajudar a resolver isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A estrutura do seu *Documento* está errada, o recomendado é que as tag `<link>`, `<title>` e `<meta>` devem estar dentro do `<head>`

Ex:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Biografia - João da Silva</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**Imagem**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para a imagem carregar basta que ela esteja na raiz do diretório em que também está o arquivo `.HTML`

Dessa forma o `href` do seu `Favicon` ficaria assim: `href="favicon.ico"`, pois está na mesma raiz que o `.html`

> Salvando-o no mesmo diretório que a página de índice do site, salvo no formato `.ico` (a maioria dos navegadores suportará favicons em formatos mais comuns como `.gif` ou `.png`, mas usar o formato ICO irá garantir que ele funcione tão bem como o Internet Explorer 6 .)

Fonte: Vc pode ler mais nessa documentação da Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Aprender/HTML/Introducao_ao_HTML/The_head_metadata_in_HTML#Adicionando_%C3%ADcones_personalizados_ao_seu_site

O indicado é que a imagem esteja na mesma parta que o `.html` como dito, mas se quiser colocar em outra pasta essa pergunta vai te ajudar a resolver o problema: [Caminho para acesso de pastas html ,css,php etc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198422/caminho-para-acesso-de-pastas-html-css-php-etc)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, eu tbm fiz mudar a imagem de png para jpg, e deu certo nao só isso como deu certo tbm colocar tudo em seu devido lugar como head e body.
Fiz umas 3 versoes do mesmo codigo e com mudanças todas elas e funcionou todas, Obrigado pela ajuda, estou voltando a aprender a programar agora entao estou com essas dificuldades. VLW

Comment: @GabrieldaSilvaSantos sem problemas jovem, o que fiz foi algo bem básico. Te indico fortemente que procuro cursos na Alura, Udemy ou qualquer outra plataforma online e compre um curço de HTML/ CSS básico. Vc não vai gastar 30 pilas e vai aprender muito!! E se não quiser gastar nada no Youtube tem muito material básico pra que esta começando! Pare umas horas para estudar o básico, vai te ajudar pro resto da vida. Abs