# Imagem SVG não aparece

Tags: html5, css3, svg

estou tentando carregar uma imagem SVG como background porém ela não aparece. Quando estou no live preview do VS Code funciona normalmente, porém quando abro o index.html diretamente pelo navegador ela simplesmente não aparece. Se alguém puder me ajudar ficaria realmente grato. link GitHub https://github.com/AlxandreLopes/fylo-landing-page.git

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Frontend Mentor | Beta sign up split layout Challenge</title>

  <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
  <style>
    .attribution { font-size: 11px; text-align: center; }
    .attribution a { color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%); }
  </style>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="header">
    <header>
      <nav>
        <svg width="120" height="35" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><path id="a" d="M.01.021h67.924V34.93H.01z"/></defs><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M0 10.215v.088l20.205 9.492 20.277-9.524v-.024L20.205.723 0 10.215zm7.284.044l12.922-6.07 12.922 6.07-12.923 6.07-12.92-6.07zm12.921 13.223L0 14.132v3.458l20.205 9.372 20.277-9.404V14.1l-20.277 9.382zm0 7.014L0 21.145v3.458l20.205 9.373 20.277-9.405v-3.458l-20.277 9.383z" fill="#BDBAFA"/><g transform="translate(52.048)"><mask id="b" fill="#fff"><use xlink:href="#a"/></mask><path id="logo-fylo" d="M63.296 17.46a5.856 5.856 0 0 0-1.562-4.03 5.247 5.247 0 0 0-1.69-1.208 4.962 4.962 0 0 0-2.062-.436c-.73 0-1.417.145-2.061.436a5.246 5.246 0 0 0-1.691 1.208 5.857 5.857 0 0 0-1.562 4.03 5.857 5.857 0 0 0 1.562 4.029 5.246 5.246 0 0 0 1.69 1.208c.645.29 1.332.435 2.062.435.73 0 1.417-.145 2.061-.435a5.247 5.247 0 0 0 1.691-1.208 5.856 5.856 0 0 0 1.562-4.03zm4.638 0c0 1.396-.258 2.69-.773 3.883a9.468 9.468 0 0 1-2.126 3.095c-.902.87-1.96 1.558-3.172 2.063a9.996 9.996 0 0 1-3.881.757 9.878 9.878 0 0 1-3.865-.757 10.021 10.021 0 0 1-3.156-2.08 9.652 9.652 0 0 1-2.126-3.11c-.515-1.192-.773-2.476-.773-3.852a9.36 9.36 0 0 1 .79-3.82 10.063 10.063 0 0 1 2.141-3.126 9.883 9.883 0 0 1 3.156-2.095 9.796 9.796 0 0 1 3.833-.757c1.374 0 2.668.252 3.88.757a10.115 10.115 0 0 1 3.173 2.063 9.426 9.426 0 0 1 2.126 3.11 9.722 9.722 0 0 1 .773 3.868zm-21.482 9.218a6.217 6.217 0 0 1-1.24.42c-.462.107-.94.16-1.433.16a7.114 7.114 0 0 1-1.98-.274 4.34 4.34 0 0 1-1.66-.886c-.472-.408-.848-.94-1.127-1.596-.279-.655-.418-1.445-.418-2.369V.021h4.734v21.306c0 .774.156 1.306.467 1.596.311.29.682.435 1.111.435.537 0 1.052-.161 1.546-.483v3.803zM36.5 8.112l-8.374 22.144c-.622 1.655-1.438 2.847-2.447 3.578-1.01.73-2.212 1.096-3.607 1.096a5.744 5.744 0 0 1-1.45-.194l-1.546-4.319c.365.172.741.306 1.128.403a4.52 4.52 0 0 0 1.095.145 4.05 4.05 0 0 0 1.996-.5c.602-.333 1.063-.95 1.385-1.853l.644-1.87-7.182-18.63H23.2l4.283 11.99 4.026-11.99H36.5zM17.015 5.308H4.905v5.995h11.95v4.061H4.904v11.41H.01V1.022h17.005v4.287z" fill="#fff" mask="url(#b)"/></g></g></svg>

        <ul id="socialMedia">
          <li><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M336 96c21.2 0 41.3 8.4 56.5 23.5S416 154.8 416 176v160c0 21.2-8.4 41.3-23.5 56.5S357.2 416 336 416H176c-21.2 0-41.3-8.4-56.5-23.5S96 357.2 96 336V176c0-21.2 8.4-41.3 23.5-56.5S154.8 96 176 96h160m0-32H176c-61.6 0-112 50.4-112 112v160c0 61.6 50.4 112 112 112h160c61.6 0 112-50.4 112-112V176c0-61.6-50.4-112-112-112z"/><path d="M360 176c-13.3 0-24-10.7-24-24s10.7-24 24-24c13.2 0 24 10.7 24 24s-10.8 24-24 24zM256 192c35.3 0 64 28.7 64 64s-28.7 64-64 64-64-28.7-64-64 28.7-64 64-64m0-32c-53 0-96 43-96 96s43 96 96 96 96-43 96-96-43-96-96-96z"/></svg></li>

          <li><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M426.8 64H85.2C73.5 64 64 73.5 64 85.2v341.6c0 11.7 9.5 21.2 21.2 21.2H256V296h-45.9v-56H256v-41.4c0-49.6 34.4-76.6 78.7-76.6 21.2 0 44 1.6 49.3 2.3v51.8h-35.3c-24.1 0-28.7 11.4-28.7 28.2V240h57.4l-7.5 56H320v152h106.8c11.7 0 21.2-9.5 21.2-21.2V85.2c0-11.7-9.5-21.2-21.2-21.2z"/></svg></li>

          <li><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M460.6 147.3L353 256.9c-.8.8-.8 2 0 2.8l75.3 80.2c5.1 5.1 5.1 13.3 0 18.4-2.5 2.5-5.9 3.8-9.2 3.8s-6.7-1.3-9.2-3.8l-75-79.9c-.8-.8-2.1-.8-2.9 0L313.7 297c-15.3 15.5-35.6 24.1-57.4 24.2-22.1.1-43.1-9.2-58.6-24.9l-17.6-17.9c-.8-.8-2.1-.8-2.9 0l-75 79.9c-2.5 2.5-5.9 3.8-9.2 3.8s-6.7-1.3-9.2-3.8c-5.1-5.1-5.1-13.3 0-18.4l75.3-80.2c.7-.8.7-2 0-2.8L51.4 147.3c-1.3-1.3-3.4-.4-3.4 1.4V368c0 17.6 14.4 32 32 32h352c17.6 0 32-14.4 32-32V148.7c0-1.8-2.2-2.6-3.4-1.4z"/><path d="M256 295.1c14.8 0 28.7-5.8 39.1-16.4L452 119c-5.5-4.4-12.3-7-19.8-7H79.9c-7.5 0-14.4 2.6-19.8 7L217 278.7c10.3 10.5 24.2 16.4 39 16.4z"/></svg></li>
        </ul>      
      </nav>        
    </header>
  </div>

  <div class="illustration" id="illustrationMain">
      <svg viewbox="0 0 458 473" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><path id="a" d="M0 .191h9.064v9.065H0z"/><path id="c" d="M0 472.793h456.636V0H0z"/></defs><g transform="translate(.692 .077)" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M338.848 411.311s-1.965-17.454 9.82-18.66c11.786-1.208 7.834-19.477 22.213-18.523 14.38.953 11.213-30.092 20.186-31.195 8.972-1.103 16.362-9.783 16.89-16.264.527-6.478 18.472-8.062 8.972 11.467-9.5 19.528 12.138 26.155-7.388 35.244-19.53 9.091 2.11 5.71-11.084 19.276-13.196 13.566-2.25 20.834-18.44 28.255-16.19 7.42-44.484 9.956-44.484 9.956l3.315-19.556z" fill="#98C5ED"/><path fill="#122C64" d="M373.17 415.74l-29.727-.97.021-.07 5.49-17.704.107.033-5.467 17.634 29.58.964z"/><path d="M337.968 416.644l-.028-.11c.15-.04 15.217-4.06 32.066-16.582 9.895-7.354 18.46-16.16 25.455-26.17 8.743-12.51 15.045-26.952 18.733-42.923l.112.026c-3.692 15.985-10 30.441-18.754 42.967-7.003 10.018-15.575 18.832-25.481 26.194-16.867 12.535-31.952 16.56-32.103 16.598" fill="#122C64"/><path fill="#122C64" d="M397.712 370.545l-2.046-24.436.112-.01 2.034 24.283 13.545-5.489.042.107zM392.397 391.79h-12.51l.009-.066 3.44-21.938.11.019-3.427 21.872h12.378z"/><g fill="#E4F3F4"><path d="M103.908 331.715h-34.27a3.79 3.79 0 1 1 0-7.58h34.27a3.79 3.79 0 0 1 0 7.58M114.993 346.875H62.626a3.79 3.79 0 1 1 0-7.58h52.367a3.79 3.79 0 1 1 0 7.58"/><path d="M95.695 335.506a3.791 3.791 0 0 1 3.79-3.792H76.083a3.792 3.792 0 0 1 0 7.582h23.404c-2.095 0-3.791-1.7-3.791-3.79"/></g><g fill="#E4F3F4"><path d="M183.44 270.816h12.092a5.497 5.497 0 0 1 0 10.992H183.44a5.496 5.496 0 1 1 0-10.992M86.368 226.842h4.946a5.497 5.497 0 0 1 0 10.994h-4.946a5.497 5.497 0 0 1 0-10.994M90.949 248.827h22.49a5.495 5.495 0 1 0 0-10.991h-6.413a5.497 5.497 0 0 1 0-10.994h67.024a5.497 5.497 0 0 1 0 10.994h-9.344a5.496 5.496 0 1 0 0 10.991h19.513a5.497 5.497 0 0 1 0 10.995h-19.513a5.496 5.496 0 1 0 0 10.992l-.021.002h5.097a5.496 5.496 0 0 1 0 10.992H98.643a5.496 5.496 0 1 1 0-10.992h5.14l-.01-.002a5.495 5.495 0 0 0 5.496-5.496 5.495 5.495 0 0 0-5.495-5.496H90.949a5.497 5.497 0 0 1 0-10.994M71.584 259.097H53.218a4.485 4.485 0 0 1 0-8.97h18.366a4.486 4.486 0 0 1 0 8.97"/></g><path d="M452.345 75.02h-17.553a4.29 4.29 0 1 1 0-8.58h5.006a4.29 4.29 0 1 0 0-8.58h-38.791a4.29 4.29 0 0 0 0 8.58h7.294a4.29 4.29 0 0 1 0 8.58h-15.23c-2.37 0-4.29 1.921-4.29 4.29a4.29 4.29 0 0 0 4.29 4.29h59.274a4.29 4.29 0 1 0 0-8.58M87.554 65.083H70a4.29 4.29 0 0 1-4.29-4.29A4.29 4.29 0 0 1 70 56.501h5.004a4.29 4.29 0 1 0 0-8.58H36.216a4.29 4.29 0 1 0 0 8.58h7.293a4.29 4.29 0 1 1 0 8.58h-15.23a4.29 4.29 0 1 0 0 8.58h59.275a4.29 4.29 0 0 0 0-8.58" fill="#E4F3F4"/><g fill="#E4F3F4"><path d="M275.007 165.32h-12.093a5.496 5.496 0 0 0-5.495 5.497 5.496 5.496 0 0 0 5.495 5.498h12.093a5.498 5.498 0 0 0 0-10.994M372.078 121.349h-4.947a5.496 5.496 0 0 0-5.496 5.496 5.495 5.495 0 0 0 5.496 5.496h4.947a5.496 5.496 0 1 0 0-10.992M367.497 143.335h-22.49a5.497 5.497 0 0 1 0-10.994h6.414a5.496 5.496 0 1 0 0-10.992h-67.025a5.496 5.496 0 0 0-5.495 5.496 5.495 5.495 0 0 0 5.495 5.496h9.346a5.496 5.496 0 0 1 5.494 5.498 5.497 5.497 0 0 1-5.494 5.496h-19.514a5.496 5.496 0 1 0 0 10.992h19.514a5.496 5.496 0 0 1 5.494 5.497 5.496 5.496 0 0 1-5.494 5.497h.02-5.097a5.498 5.498 0 1 0 0 10.994h71.136a5.497 5.497 0 1 0 0-10.994h-5.14.012a5.497 5.497 0 1 1 0-10.994h12.824a5.496 5.496 0 1 0 0-10.992"/></g><path d="M326.95 444.585s-94.144-61.38-81.373-97.183c12.772-35.804 87.453 56.222 90.831 91.597l-9.459 5.586z" fill="#DE8486"/><path d="M331.651 441.833c-23.95-20.15-45.256-46.17-58.913-64.452-14.794-19.804-24.047-35.042-24.139-35.192l.109-.067c.091.152 9.341 15.384 24.134 35.185 13.65 18.274 34.95 44.286 58.89 64.43l-.08.096z" fill="#122C64"/><path fill="#122C64" d="M272.41 376.856l-.072-.028-25.32-10.089.046-.117 25.248 10.06 4.907-26.82.125.021zM287.245 395.842l-.07-.023-27.59-8.94.04-.12 27.52 8.916 5.154-31.528.126.02zM304.39 415.547l-.072-.025-26.853-9.715.043-.12 26.78 9.688 5.114-30.473.126.02zM327.082 437.85l-.087-.04-24.354-10.676.05-.117 24.266 10.639.257-24.462h.128z"/><path d="M310.32 418.098s-12.423-33.605-11.961-47.208l4.667 5.542 13.84 43.415.34 2.825-4.793-1.143-2.094-3.431z" fill="#122C64"/><path d="M323.507 444.54s-44.905-103.024-14.558-125.913c30.35-22.889 42.154 95.037 25.53 126.447l-10.972-.534z" fill="#DE8486"/><path d="M328.948 444.826c-8.931-29.997-12.427-63.447-13.788-86.224-1.473-24.677-.825-42.492-.819-42.67l.127.005c-.007.178-.654 17.988.819 42.659 1.36 22.77 4.855 56.207 13.782 86.194l-.121.036z" fill="#122C64"/><path fill="#122C64" d="M315.176 357.982l-.045-.064-15.608-22.345.104-.072 15.564 22.281 18.84-19.708.092.089zM317.133 381.997l-.046-.059-18.135-22.631.1-.08 18.088 22.575 21.637-23.503.094.085zM320.623 407.882l-.047-.062-17.093-22.875.104-.076 17.046 22.813 21.02-22.644.094.086zM327.32 438.986l-.052-.08-14.475-22.307.107-.07 14.423 22.227 13.662-20.294.104.071z"/><path d="M272.57 401.009s47.888 18.576 65.756 35.179l-3.948 3.99-60.506-33.722 4.79.389-6.092-5.836z" fill="#122C64"/><path d="M332.65 448.196s-91.354-4.586-97.044-34.996c-5.69-30.41 84.535 3.698 101.407 27.191l-4.363 7.805z" fill="#DE8486"/><path d="M334.827 444.346c-25.101-4.357-50.746-13.924-67.841-21.182-18.52-7.865-31.27-14.789-31.397-14.859l.06-.11c.127.068 12.873 6.99 31.389 14.852 17.087 7.255 42.723 16.82 67.811 21.174l-.022.125z" fill="#122C64"/><path fill="#122C64" d="M244.544 426.22l-.02-.125 21.864-3.27-7.535-20.858.118-.043 7.588 21.003-.075.011zM261.636 435.232l-.026-.124 22.99-5.004-9.288-24.27.12-.045 9.34 24.408-.072.016zM281.964 441.216l-.023-.125 22.789-4.16-8.887-23.51.119-.046 8.94 23.654-.075.014zM308.406 445.896l-.015-.126 21.405-2.46-9.833-17.292.11-.063 9.93 17.458z"/><path fill="#FCFCFC" d="M388.508 159.508l-1.419 1.87-.186 2.34-1.87-1.42-2.34-.185 1.419-1.87.186-2.34 1.87 1.417zM425.135 125.79l-2.224 2.932-.293 3.67-2.933-2.226-3.669-.29 2.226-2.934.291-3.669 2.934 2.226zM430.131 12.87l-2.224 2.932-.293 3.67-2.932-2.227-3.67-.29 2.227-2.933.29-3.67 2.934 2.227zM361.527 314.399l-1.419 1.87-.186 2.34-1.87-1.419-2.34-.186 1.419-1.87.186-2.341 1.87 1.418zM123.116 100.06l-1.423 1.866-.192 2.34-1.866-1.423-2.34-.191 1.424-1.868.19-2.34 1.868 1.423z"/><g transform="translate(0 143.254)"><mask id="b" fill="#fff"><use xlink:href="#a"/></mask><path fill="#FCFCFC" mask="url(#b)" d="M9.064 2.694L6.852 5.607l-.29 3.649-2.915-2.212L0 6.755 2.213 3.84 2.5.19l2.915 2.212z"/></g><path fill="#FCFCFC" d="M270.88 391.776l-2.212 2.913-.29 3.649-2.915-2.213-3.646-.289 2.212-2.915.288-3.649 2.916 2.213zM118.987 398.772l-2.212 2.912-.29 3.649-2.915-2.213-3.648-.288 2.213-2.916.29-3.649 2.914 2.213zM15.188 299.683a4.296 4.296 0 1 1-8.592 0 4.296 4.296 0 0 1 8.592 0M427.982 235.473a2.637 2.637 0 1 1-5.273.002 2.637 2.637 0 0 1 5.273-.002M29.263 2.637a2.637 2.637 0 1 1-5.275 0 2.637 2.637 0 0 1 5.275 0M162.79 19.88a3.002 3.002 0 1 1-6.005 0 3.002 3.002 0 0 1 6.005 0"/><path d="M114.055 167.022h96.128v-25.32c0-5.723 4.64-10.364 10.364-10.364h93.855c5.723 0 10.363 4.64 10.363 10.365v171.032H118.874c-8.386 0-15.184-6.797-15.184-15.183V177.386c0-5.723 4.64-10.364 10.365-10.364" fill="#EFD456"/><path d="M223.048 275.352h-20.307c-13.39 0-24.245-10.855-24.245-24.245v-20.308c0-13.39 10.854-24.244 24.245-24.244h20.307c13.39 0 24.246 10.854 24.246 24.244v20.308c0 13.39-10.855 24.245-24.246 24.245" fill="#FFF"/><path d="M224.31 234.64c0-6.506-5.273-11.78-11.779-11.78-6.505 0-11.777 5.274-11.777 11.78 0 4.869 2.956 9.048 7.171 10.841l-4.511 10.432h19.21l-4.552-10.88c3.71-1.983 6.238-5.891 6.238-10.393" fill="#021550"/><mask id="d" fill="#fff"><use xlink:href="#c"/></mask><path fill="#FFF" mask="url(#d)" d="M113.316 296.784h1.749v-88.172h-1.749zM113.316 200.943h1.749v-15.032h-1.749z"/><path d="M270.733 253.242a3.83 3.83 0 1 1 5.412 5.415 3.83 3.83 0 0 1-5.412-5.415m8.612 8.6a8.446 8.446 0 0 0-3.522-14.057c.02-.127.033-.255.033-.385l-.038-24.108a2.334 2.334 0 0 0-4.666.004v.457h-4.29a1.534 1.534 0 0 0 0 3.065h4.29v4.161h-4.29a1.534 1.534 0 0 0 0 3.065h4.29v13.365c0 .104.007.205.02.305a8.446 8.446 0 0 0-3.774 14.127 8.446 8.446 0 0 0 11.947 0" fill="#010101" mask="url(#d)"/><path d="M234.919 222.345v21.986c0 6.285-6.18 11.91-11.696 15.677-4.34 2.968-8.265 4.778-8.424 4.847h-.006s-20.128-9.284-20.128-20.524v-21.986l20.134-6.441 20.12 6.44z" fill="#A8D626" mask="url(#d)"/><path d="M214.797 215.903l-.001.001v48.952c.354-.148 20.125-9.288 20.125-20.526v-21.987l-20.124-6.44z" fill="#448E1B" mask="url(#d)"/><path fill="#FFF" mask="url(#d)" d="M202.466 238.731l10.249 10.475 16.777-16.598-4.353-3.991-12.244 12.336-6.62-5.805z"/><path d="M330.218 305.46s-18.596 138.19-18.662 158.69l11.729.574s27.593-117.326 34.431-123.468c0 0 2.83-.47 3.923 0 1.092.472-3.931 118.243-5.754 125.848l12.44.992s25.454-132.572 24.477-161.805c0 0-5.204-14.683-26.967-13.36-21.762 1.322-33.43-2.054-35.617 12.53" fill="#2A2B2A" mask="url(#d)"/><path d="M324.605 463.989c-3.736-.495-10.064-.683-13.82-.341a44.04 44.04 0 0 1-9.654 4.2c-.987.295-2.024.578-2.783 1.222-.758.644-1.129 1.78-.517 2.543.534.666 1.554.794 2.46.857 6.935.475 16.446.459 23.355-.267.414-.044.855-.1 1.17-.348.251-.2.384-.491.49-.779.866-2.312.606-4.951-.7-7.087M369.877 462.186s-12.542-.033-14.06.764c-1.516.797-3.07 8.007-.584 9.04 2.486 1.032 28.274-1.031 28.274-1.031s2.306-2.965-4.612-4.77c-6.918-1.807-8-1.798-9.018-4.003" fill="#07033B" mask="url(#d)"/><path d="M389.953 228.837c3.002 3.217 5.77 6.675 8.143 10.408 3.571 5.62 6.21 11.802 8.833 17.953 3.42 8.023 6.903 16.32 7.02 25.081.038 2.835-.306 5.757-1.646 8.234-1.258 2.327-3.298 4.09-5.39 5.653-4.284 3.2-9.523 5.889-14.7 4.752 1.019-2.911 2.35-6.16 5.178-7.21.852-.317 1.786-.401 2.589-.837.899-.49 1.533-1.369 2.058-2.267 3.347-5.742 3.103-13.49-.599-18.997-1.623-2.413-3.802-4.364-5.951-6.293-5.628-5.05-11.307-10.246-15.21-16.797-3.493-5.857-5.858-13.836-3.89-20.68 2.138-7.424 10.096-2.715 13.565 1" fill="#0ABC85" mask="url(#d)"/><path d="M268.784 268.664c-1.153-.394-2.363-.908-3.055-1.957-.602-.914-.707-2.076-.785-3.18-.037-.5-.054-1.057.25-1.442.35-.44.971-.473 1.52-.472l3.401.01c.81.002 1.74-.054 2.233-.722.157-.215.253-.473.417-.682.414-.52 1.176-.591 1.792-.376.619.214 1.137.657 1.67 1.046a11.902 11.902 0 0 0 5.14 2.143c.412.063.84.11 1.21.315.531.296.864.88 1.073 1.471.524 1.487.42 3.522-.485 4.83-.818 1.187-1.993.896-3.283.886a35.192 35.192 0 0 1-11.098-1.87" fill="#FCE0D3" mask="url(#d)"/><path d="M348.336 241.694l-.976-13.034c-.108-1.417-.28-2.978-1.326-3.94-1.6-1.473-4.172-.686-6.081.351-7.818 4.247-13.716 11.23-19.449 18.031-5.732 6.801-11.695 13.746-19.576 17.872-5.822 3.045-10.85.882-17.087 1.09-.292.012-.645.046-1.036.104-.015.082-.012.156-.035.24-.28 1.07-.538 3.944-.84 5.01-.094.59-.165 1.182-.27 1.77-.123.699-.2 1.621-.526 2.316 4.45.974 10.998.82 13.12.796 6.504-.073 12.983-1.221 19.177-3.182 10.8-3.42 20.72-9.225 29.823-15.968 1.748-1.294 3.535-2.704 4.445-4.68.962-2.084.81-4.488.637-6.776" fill="#0ABC85" mask="url(#d)"/><path d="M352.858 171.212c-4.476 3.78-6.182 9.192-6.927 14.461a52.92 52.92 0 0 0-.258 12.61c.414 4.174 1.393 8.486 4.351 12.02 2.957 3.534 8.316 6.096 13.376 5.312 5.778-.894 9.134-5.511 11.6-9.763 3.57-6.159 6.786-12.72 6.456-19.63-.312-6.544-4.486-11.749-10.108-16.41-5.273-4.372-13.898-2.477-18.49 1.4" fill="#FCE0D3" mask="url(#d)"/><path d="M395.822 319.278c.012-.051.036-.098.025-.158-4.266-26.406.954-56.382-8.279-81.772l-5.121-11.487s-5.83-8.995-27.483-6.588c-15.47 1.718-14.202 20.51-14.202 20.51l.102-.006c-.486 5.483-11.59 47.069-13.102 68.628l-.563 8.007c-.088 1.264-1.042 3.623.681 4.741 1.202.78 10.81.779 12.326.84 4.599.186 9.252.162 13.854.056 16.371-.371 25.88 1.686 41.212-2.076.502-.124.657-.437.55-.695" fill="#06D79D" mask="url(#d)"/><path d="M359.58 257.992c-1.703-6.309-1.652-11.131-2.562-18.168-.841-6.51-1.86-12.913-3.13-19.04-.006-.02-.015-.024-.021-.039-.023-.382-.27-.603-.399-.194-1.198 3.825-2.611 6.86-4.347 9.342-.26.374-.198 1.254.083 1.47.949.73 2.98 1.8 3.624 3.77.896 2.739-.972 5.983-1.777 7.54-.154.299-.115.852 0 1.163 2.562 6.841 5.433 12.99 8.647 18.144.291.465.552-.296.474-.926.089-.17-.512-2.765-.592-3.062M370.458 229.28c-1.263 2.34-2.6 4.176-4.012 5.739-.254.283-.44 1.279-.18 1.88.812 1.874 1.648 3.366 2.587 4.611-2.468 7.54-4.987 14.84-8.007 20.728.883-12.313 1.91-24.584 3.37-36.477.432-3.508.626-7.036 2.2-6.136 1.187.676 2.497 3.564 3.585 5.115.156.223 1.6 1.963 1.594 2.275-.01.488-.993 1.999-1.137 2.266" fill="#006FD0" mask="url(#d)"/><path d="M360.445 236.921c-.041.008-.082.017-.124.022.04-.001.083-.016.124-.022" fill="#FFF" mask="url(#d)"/><path d="M357.032 231.042c-.463-1.383-1.332-3.298-1.139-5.074.133-1.206.65-1.797 1.23-1.814a6.478 6.478 0 0 1 3.063-1.019c.736-.051 2.238-.444 2.714 1.02.445 1.366-.177 3.775-.462 5.008-.494 2.136-1.17 4.05-1.93 5.884-.075.18-.15.34-.226.499l.003.005c.529 2.666 2.109 8.615 2.733 14.289 1.527-11.315 3.69-28.402 3.69-28.402s-.672-5.928-13.24-.886c0 0 1.8 12.683 3.423 23.886.474-2.713 1.18-5.252 1.953-8.732-.728-1.126-1.353-3.293-1.812-4.664" fill="#FFF" mask="url(#d)"/><path d="M360.699 236.853c-.024.007-.04.02-.067.026a.426.426 0 0 0 .067-.026" fill="#FFF" mask="url(#d)"/><path d="M360.59 236.897c.016-.005.027-.013.043-.018a.815.815 0 0 1-.189.042c.049-.009.098-.01.146-.024" fill="#004161" mask="url(#d)"/><path d="M361.701 259.021c.24-1.351.733-4.844 1.317-9.18-.623-5.676-2.204-11.624-2.733-14.29l-.002-.002c.074-.162.15-.323.225-.502.76-1.834 1.436-3.748 1.93-5.885.285-1.232.907-3.64.462-5.008-.476-1.463-1.978-1.07-2.714-1.018a6.467 6.467 0 0 0-3.064 1.019c-.578.017-1.096.607-1.229 1.813-.193 1.775.676 3.69 1.139 5.075.458 1.37 1.084 3.537 1.812 4.664-.773 3.48-1.48 6.018-1.953 8.732 1.255 8.669 2.403 16.45 2.526 16.782.139.374.486 1.021.904 1.008.042-.008.083-.03.123-.048.063-.023.124-.042.189-.1.025-.016.042-.043.066-.062.333-.355.686-1.217 1.002-2.998" fill="#07033B" mask="url(#d)"/><path d="M391.027 291.836c-.874-.648-1.77-1.308-2.804-1.646-.715-.232-1.47-.306-2.22-.331-1.112-.038-2.322.059-3.158.795-.645.571-.953 1.435-1.115 2.281a9.156 9.156 0 0 0 .18 4.16c.136.483.319.968.658 1.337.376.41.906.638 1.43.82 2.415.84 5.015.94 7.569 1.032 1.302.048 2.869-.044 3.514-1.176.232-.405.295-.88.355-1.342.074-.567.452-1.68.289-2.216-.155-.512-.75-.79-1.193-1.119l-3.505-2.595" fill="#FCE0D3" mask="url(#d)"/><path d="M345.931 185.673s-.005-6.585 2.533-13.17c0 0 1.13-3.35 0-5.205-2.442-4.004 23.222-15.822 33.108 3.69 9.886 19.51-4.793 31.677-4.793 31.677s.656-6.428-.048-8.679c-.703-2.25-3.797-3.375-3.797 0 0 3.376-1.34.142-1.34.142s-1.753-6.47 1.762-8.017c3.515-1.545 4.772-11.39-1.762-11.39-6.534 0-14.269 6.75-18.91 4.782 0 0-4.646-2.424-6.753 6.17" fill="#B97C00" mask="url(#d)"/><path d="M346.863 180.468s.834-5.912-2.941-7.405c0 0-4.648-2.18-2.421-9.01 0 0 .867-2.01 2.419-2.469 0 0 .761-.468.84 1.182.08 1.65 4.732 4.574 8.709 2.546l-6.606 15.156z" fill="#B97C00" mask="url(#d)"/></g></svg>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <main>
      <h1>All your files in one secure location, <br> accessible anywhere!!!</h1>

      <p id="description">Fylo stores all your most important files in one secure location. Access them wherever you need, share and collaborate with friends, family and co-workers.</p>  

      <p id="signUp">Sign up for early access</p>
    </main>

    <form action="">        
      <input id="box" type="email">
      <input id="btn" type="button" value="Sign Up"> 
    </form>

    <footer>
      <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
    </footer>
  </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/* RESET */

h1, p, ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;  
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

/* General Style */

body{  
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 40px 0 40px;
  background-image: url(/images/bg-intro.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-size: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:   
  "header"
  "illustration"
  "main";  
}

/* Grid Template */


.header{

  grid-area: header;
}

.illustration{
  grid-area: illustration;
}

.main{
  grid-area: main;
}

/* Header */

nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

#socialMedia{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;  
}

#socialMedia svg{
  height: 25px;
  fill: white;
}

li + li{
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#illustrationMain{
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px; 
  margin-bottom: 35%;
}

/* Main */

h1{
  font-size: 1.8em;

  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
h1, #signUp, footer{
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: hsl(243, 87%, 12%);
}

#description{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 50%);
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

/* Form */

form{
  display: grid;   
}

#signUp, input{
  margin-bottom: 20px;  
}

#box{
  border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 50%);
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 40px;
}

#btn{
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: hsl(163, 95%, 43%);
  border: none;
  height: 43px;
  width: 150px;  
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

/* Footer */

footer{
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 1em;
}

/* Queries */

@media(min-width:1440px){
  body{
    grid-template-areas:
    "illustration header"
    "illustration main";
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    background-image: none;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
  }

  #socialMedia li svg, #logo-fylo{
    fill: hsl(243, 87%, 12%);
  }

  #illustrationMain{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;    
    background-image: linear-gradient(hsl(243, 87%, 12%), hsl(243, 86%, 85%));
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100% !important;    
    margin-top:0 !important; 
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  }  

  #illustrationMain svg{    
    width: 50%;
  }

  .header, .main{
    padding: 0 60px;    
  }

  .main{
    max-width: 75%;
  }

  form{    
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr; 
    justify-content: space-between;
    grid-gap: 30px;
  }


  #btn{
    width: 100% !important;
  }  
}
```

SVG

```
<svg width="375" height="445" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs><linearGradient x1="14.569%" y1="-6.457%" x2="132.964%" y2="153.753%" id="a"><stop stop-color="#110A6D" offset="0%"/><stop stop-color="#BDBAFA" offset="100%"/><stop stop-color="#BDBAFA" offset="100%"/></linearGradient></defs><path d="M0 376.28c67.572-32.674 124.62-32.674 171.144 0 69.787 49.013 141.558 86.511 242.423 59.172 67.244-18.226 67.244-163.377 0-435.452H0v376.28z" fill="url(#a)" fill-rule="evenodd"/></svg>
```

Comment: E cadê seu html? Cade o código do svg? Abre o arquivo svg no vscode, copia o código dele e cola aqui editando a pergunta, aproveita e coloca tbm o html

Comment: Seu arquivo `.css` está dentro de alguma pasta, ou está na raiz do site junto com o arquivo `.html`? Coloca ai o `<head>` do seu documento, to achando que seu problema não é com o SVG

Comment: Está na raiz junto ao .html, vou por o <head> mais o link do repositório, obrigado.

Comment: Cara aqui testando localmente funcionou normal... seu problema deve ser com as pastas e os caminhos dos arquivos. Seria interessande vc colocar uma imagem de como estão as pastas e o `<head>` do documento com o que vc está indexando nele de .css etc http://prntscr.com/omg4dc olha a imagem funcionando

Comment: Resolvido, tanto o background-image: url(./images/bg-intro.svg); como o background-image: url(images/bg-intro.svg); resolveram o problema. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Sim sim, como falei na resposta ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema é essa barra `/` que vc colocou no caminha da imagem do background...

Se o .css e a pasta imagem estão na raiz do site, vc não precisa colocar assim `background-image: url(/images/bg-intro.svg);` e essa `/images` faz o css procurar na pasta raiz do diretório e não dentro da pasta local o correto seria apenas `background-image: url(images/bg-intro.svg);` sem a `/` no início do *path*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Leitura recomendada: [Caminho para acesso de pastas html ,css,php etc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198422/caminho-para-acesso-de-pastas-html-css-php-etc)

Comment: Perfeito, esclareceu totalmente a minha dúvida e tive o meu problema sanado. Muitíssimo obrigado

Comment: @Alexandre caminha de pasta as vezes confunde mesmo rss, mas que bom que resolveu, e melhor ainda que não era no SVG rss