# Concatenar variável CSS com texto plano

Tags: css

preciso de uma ajuda com **CSS variáveis** mas não sei se será possível fazer o que desejo.

Tenho o **background** de um **botão** da forma abaixo

```
.btn-view {
    background: url(../../assets/imgs/eye.jpg); 
}
```

Mas gostaria de criar uma **variável no root** com o **domínio do site** e estou fazendo como abaixo

```
:root {
    --dominioSite: 'https://meudominio.com';
}
```

Agora a ideia é jogar o valor dessa variável dento de um **bakground** como abaixo:

```
.btn-view {
    --dominio : var(--dominioSite) + '/assets/imgs/eye.jpg';
    background: url(--dominio);
}
```

Mas não funciona.

Será que tem como fazer isso?

E, se tiver, seria mesmo uma boa prática?

Comment: Olá, acho que não suporta a concatenação de duas Strings na url. Mas voce pode usar o JavaScript para fazer essa modificações, pois no Js aceita variáveis concatenadas.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno. Mas eu tenho essa feature no lado do CSS do JS  e do PHP para pegar o domínio e evitar os ../../ da vida . Da forma que tu disse eu teria que misturar JS com CSS e não é uma boa prática.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem como fazer o que pretende utilizando apenas CSS, isso porque, quando você define a variável no CSS `--dominioSite` com o valor `https://meudominio.com` automaticamente o navegador não vai entender o que é este valor e provavelmente vai ignorar.

Isso acontece, justamente porque as variáveis em CSS são semelhantes as propriedades CSS (`propriedade` + `valor`) só que de forma com nomes customizados ou seja, precisam ter valores válidos em código CSS para poderem funcionar como, por exemplo, `border 1px solid black`, `red`, `10px`, `uppercase`, `contain` e etc. E o valor passado como URL entre as aspas (`''`) não é válido.

O máximo que você conseguiria fazer com o CSS é usar a propriedade [content](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/content) em conjunto os pseudo-elementos [::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/::before) ou [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/::after) para "concatenar" duas strings:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .btn-view::after {
      content: "https://meudominio.com" "/assets/imgs/eye.jpg";
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="btn-view"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Porém, tanto `::before` quanto `::after` são usados para gerarem conteúdo no elemento (adicionando conteúdo antes e depois) e não de certa forma incorporar algo no elemento e os mesmos não dariam para serem usados como valores em conjunto com as variáveis do CSS já que voltaria ao que foi dito antes os valores seriam inválidos. Por tanto, o melhor a se fazer é usar JavaScript para contornar o que deseja fazer.

Comment: entendi, então não há como acabar com os ../../ da vida né? Pelo menos por enquanto. Obrigado!

Comment: @CarlosRocha, como assim acabar com os `../../`? Eles são usados apenas para [acessar o diretório](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198422/caminho-para-acesso-de-pastas-html-css-php-etc) de um terminado arquivo.

Comment: url(../../assets/imgs/eye.jpg); MUDOU pata url(.assets/imgs/eye.jpg);